# Distinguishable knots (with constraints) over polyhedra

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, knot-theory, polyhedra

I'm trying to find the number of distinguishable knot projections over certain convex regular polyhedra according to the following constraints.  On each face on the polyhedron the knot will have a local form such as this:

[image: binding]

thereby holding the knot in place.  Thus the number of edges of each face must be even, as each section of the knot enters from one edge and leaves on another edge.  (The knot curve traverses each polyhedron edge exactly once.)  This restricts the permissible polyhedra to ones in which all faces have an even number of edges, for example:

[image: permissible polyhedra]

(Imagine putting a greased rubber band atop a cube, where every face is traversed as in the top figure.)

I find a permissible knot path over a permissible polyhedron as follows.  I form the dual graph $g$ with one vertex corresponding to each polyhedron face, and the graph edges correspond to the polyhedron edges shared by faces.  I then compute an Eulerian cycle through the graph.  This is an allowable path of the closed knot curve over the surface of the polyhedron.

Here, in red, is a knot projection corresponding to one of the possible Eulerian cycles shown atop the net representation of a cube:

[image: Eulerian cycle]

I've added blue dots in the center of each of the cube's faces, to clarify my next point.

In this case, on each face there are two crossings of the knot.  On each face we are free to choose one of two possible assignments of these crossings, to ensure the linkage constraint in the first figure, above.

[Note:  The cube is a special case.  I've assumed that each section of the knot must make a $90^\circ$ "L" turn to ensure the binding model in my top figure.  If the combinatorics is simpler/solvable without that constraint, fine.]

Of course by "distinguishable" for my full problem I mean that one cannot rotate one knotted polyhedron to correspond to another... both in the sequence of faces traversed by the knot *AND* the sequences of crossings.

Might the answer be as simple as $N_p 2^d$, where $N_p$ is the number of distinguishable paths, and $d$ is the number of faces?

First:  Has this problem been solved?  The closest paper I could find was [this one](https://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2011/bridges2011-59.pdf), which does not quite address the combinatorical problem.  I think I have a handle, from graph theory, on the number of distinguishable paths of the knot, as it is essentially the number of distinguishable Eulerian cycles through an undirected polyhedron graph, as defined above.

But the incorporation of the crossing structure makes the overall problem rather tricky.... or perhaps not (if the path and crossing assignments are truly independent).

A special case subproblem:  Can the trivial knot (unknot) be embedded in a cube given these constraints in multiple distinguishable ways?  (I've tried to create such distinguishable knot embeddings by hand, but so far have failed.)

Likewise, can a non-trivial knot (e.g., trefoil) be mapped to the surface of a cube in more than one distinguishable way?